# Jquery how to hide or show an element according to a condition

Tags: jquery

I've this working code with jQuery:

```
if ( condition ) {
      $elem.hide()
} else {
      $elem.show()
}
```

I want to know if there is any method that allows me to do something like:

```
      $elem.visible(condition)
```

or

```
      $elem.apply( condition ? 'hide' : 'show')
```

What I want is reduce it to a single line.

I know I can extend `jQuery` and add a function to do that easily, but is there a native jquery function that allows me to do that or something similar?

Comment: *"I want to know if there is any method that..."* I suggest reading through the [jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com) beginning to end. It only takes an hour, two tops. Heck, to get the answer to this question, you don't even have to read the whole thing, just read through the list of functions on the first page.

Answer (score 0):

Finally found it!

```
$elem.toggle( condition )
```